# Service Broker - A previously existing connection with the same peer was detected during connection handshake.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, connectivity, service-broker

There are good questions about service broker [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/18359/22336), [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222530/is-there-any-advantage-when-troubleshooting-service-broker-to-create-the-queue) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223278/service-broker-poison-message-how-to-handle-how-to-enable-poison-messase-ha).

In none of those questions I see the following error message:

> Service Broker login attempt by user 'MYCOMPANY_USA\sqlservice.'
>   failed with error: 'A previously existing connection with the same
>   peer was detected during connection handshake. This connection lost
>   the arbitration and it will be closed. All traffic will be redirected
>   to the previously existing connection. This is an informational
>   message only. No user action is required. State 80.'.  [SERVER:
>   10.31.8.216]

But [on this question there is a very similar message](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23397/event-notification-service-broker-no-inserts-anymore-previously-existing-c), but no answer.

I got this message by running the following script:

```
;WITH cte_HADR AS (SELECT object_name, CONVERT(XML, event_data) AS data
FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file('AlwaysOn*.xel', null, null, null)
WHERE object_name = 'error_reported'
)

SELECT data.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]','datetime') AS [timestamp],
       data.value('(/event/data[@name=''error_number''])[1]','int') AS [error_number],
       data.value('(/event/data[@name=''message''])[1]','varchar(max)') AS [message]
FROM cte_HADR
WHERE data.value('(/event/data[@name=''error_number''])[1]','int') = 28048
order by data.value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]','datetime') DESC
```

[image]

What could be possible things to look at?

we do have more than one service broker sessions